# Log4j: How to use custom marker(variable) between two processes in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have application which process objects sequentially.

It takes object A and takes some values from object A, like `ID` for example  in one process with PID number 1 and keep processing object A in process with PID number 2. How can I have Id of object A in two diffrent processes with LOG4J?

Second what is my application will process more then one object at the same time(parallel processing) how would I identify log event with ID value of each object.

Comment: If the object has an ID, and it's the "same" object in both processes, I don't understand the problem. You can output whatever you want in your log messages... like the ID of an object. You could use an MDC or NDC as well.

Comment: I would like to, but MDC aor NDC exist in scope of one process

Comment: NDC/MDC answers "how to display it". Is your object "id" not really an ID, but its default `toString()`? If that's the case, obviously you *can't*, unless you pass in info from one thread to another.

Comment: Correct sir. My ID not realy the ID. Just peace if xml element value. So as I understand I can pass values from one thread of one process to other thread of other process??